# How can i send a url within push message?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification to my phonegap app. The app runs with an external website. So i can send push notifications, no problem and everything works very well.

How can i send an url with the push message, that will be open the app and load the specific page when i click on the push message?

Here ist my code:

```
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $message = array(
        'title' => $data['mtitle'],
        'message' => $data['mdesc'],
        'subtitle' => '',
        'tickerText' => '',
        'msgcnt' => 1,
        'vibrate' => 1,
        'contents' => 'http://www.domain.com/hello/'
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' .self::$API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($reg_id),
        'data' => $message,
    );

    return PushNotifications::useCurl($url, $headers, json_encode($fields));
```

Comment: For hybrid mobile application development you are using phonegap or you are using specific framework like ionic or other?

Comment: I using phonegap without framework

Comment: I think there should be one method which is called when push message open from notification drawer so from this method you can get message and manage your link as your requirement.